# error 500 with plugin called metabox in wp

Tags: php, wordpress

So I installed this theme called aqura and another one, both of them gave me an error 500 and I kept searching how to overcome that problem till I found out that the problem is in a plugin called metabox, once it is installed the website go down giving error 500... but without it the whole theme isn't functional as well...
I managed to install the 2 plugins causing the problem related to metabox but I got this error: --- Fatal error: Class 'RWMB_Field' not found in /home/haddadmokhtar/public_html/wp-content/plugins/aqura-met‌​abox-group/meta-box-‌​group/class-rwmb-gro‌​up-field.php on line 14
That's the code of the whole file:

/**
 * Class for group field.
 * @package    Meta Box
 * @subpackage Meta Box Group
 */
class RWMB_Group_Field extends RWMB_Field
{
    /**
     * Queue to store the group fields' meta(s). Used to get child field meta.
     * @var array
     */
    protected static $meta_queue = array();

```
/**
 * Add hooks for sub-fields.
 */
public static function add_actions()
{
    // Group field is the 1st param
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach ( $args[0]['fields'] as $field )
    {
        RWMB_Field::call( $field, 'add_actions' );
    }
}

/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
public static function admin_enqueue_scripts()
{
    // Group field is the 1st param
    $args   = func_get_args();
    $fields = $args[0]['fields'];

    // Load clone script conditionally
    foreach ( $fields as $field )
    {
        if ( $field['clone'] )
        {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'rwmb-clone', RWMB_JS_URL . 'clone.js', array( 'jquery-ui-sortable' ), RWMB_VER, true );
            break;
        }
    }

    // Enqueue sub-fields scripts and styles.
    foreach ( $fields as $field )
    {
        RWMB_Field::call( $field, 'admin_enqueue_scripts' );
    }

    // Use helper function to get correct URL to current folder, which can be used in themes/plugins.
    list( , $url ) = RWMB_Loader::get_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'rwmb-group', $url . 'group.css', '', '1.1.2' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'rwmb-group', $url . 'group.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.1.2', true );
}

/**
 * Get group field HTML.
 *
 * @param mixed $meta
 * @param array $field
 * @return string
 */
public static function html( $meta, $field )
{
    ob_start();

    // Add filter to child field meta value, make sure it's added only once
    if ( empty( self::$meta_queue ) )
    {
        add_filter( 'rwmb_field_meta', array( __CLASS__, 'child_field_meta' ), 10, 3 );
    }

    // Add group value to the queue
    array_unshift( self::$meta_queue, $meta );

    // Add clone index to make sure each child field has an unique ID.
    $clone_index = '';
    if ( $field['clone'] && preg_match( '|_\d+$|', $field['id'], $match ) )
    {
        $clone_index = $match[0];
    }

    foreach ( $field['fields'] as $child_field )
    {
        $child_field['field_name']       = self::child_field_name( $field['field_name'], $child_field['field_name'] );
        $child_field['attributes']['id'] = ( isset( $child_field['attributes']['id'] ) ? $child_field['attributes']['id'] : $child_field['id'] ) . $clone_index;
        self::call( 'show', $child_field, RWMB_Group::$saved );
    }

    // Remove group value from the queue
    array_shift( self::$meta_queue );

    // Remove filter to child field meta value and reset class's parent field's meta
    if ( empty( self::$meta_queue ) )
    {
        remove_filter( 'rwmb_field_meta', array( __CLASS__, 'child_field_meta' ) );
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
}

/**
 * Change the way we get meta value for child fields
 *
 * @param mixed $meta        Meta value
 * @param array $child_field Child field
 * @param bool  $saved       Has the meta box been saved?
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public static function child_field_meta( $meta, $child_field, $saved )
{
    $group_meta = reset( self::$meta_queue );
    $child_id   = $child_field['id'];
    if ( isset( $group_meta[$child_id] ) )
    {
        $meta = $group_meta[$child_id];
    }
    if ( ! $saved && isset( $child_field['std'] ) )
    {
        $meta = $child_field['std'];
    }

    /**
     * Make sure meta value is an array for clonable and multiple fields
     * @see RWMB_Field::meta()
     */
    if ( $child_field['clone'] || $child_field['multiple'] )
    {
        if ( empty( $meta ) || ! is_array( $meta ) )
        {
            /**
             * Note: if field is clonable, $meta must be an array with values
             * so that the foreach loop in self::show() runs properly
             * @see RWMB_Field::show()
             */
            $meta = $child_field['clone'] ? array( '' ) : array();
        }
    }
    return $meta;
}

/**
 * Get meta value, make sure value is an array (of arrays if field is cloneable)
 * Don't escape value
 *
 * @param int   $post_id
 * @param bool  $saved
 * @param array $field
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public static function meta( $post_id, $saved, $field )
{
    $meta = get_post_meta( $post_id, $field['id'], true ); // Always save as single value

    // Use $field['std'] only when the meta box hasn't been saved (i.e. the first time we run)
    $meta = ! $saved && '' === $meta ? $field['std'] : $meta;

    // Make sure returned value is an array
    if ( empty( $meta ) )
        $meta = array();

    // If cloneable, make sure each sub-value is an array
    if ( $field['clone'] )
    {
        // Make sure there's at least 1 sub-value
        if ( empty( $meta ) )
            $meta[0] = array();

        foreach ( $meta as $k => $v )
        {
            $meta[$k] = (array) $v;
        }
    }

    return $meta;
}

/**
 * Change child field name to form parent[child]
 *
 * @param string $parent Parent field's name
 * @param string $child  Child field's name
 * @return string
 */
public static function child_field_name( $parent, $child )
{
    $pos  = strpos( $child, '[' );
    $pos  = false === $pos ? strlen( $child ) : $pos;
    $name = $parent . '[' . substr( $child, 0, $pos ) . ']' . substr( $child, $pos );

    return $name;
}

/**
 * Set value of meta before saving into database
 *
 * @param mixed $new
 * @param mixed $old
 * @param int   $post_id
 * @param array $field
 *
 * @return int
 */
public static function value( $new, $old, $post_id, $field )
{
    $sanitized = array();
    foreach ( $new as $key => $value )
    {
        if ( is_array( $value ) && ! empty( $value ) )
        {
            $value = self::value( $value, '', '', '' );
        }
        if ( '' !== $value && array() !== $value )
        {
            if ( is_int( $key ) )
            {
                $sanitized[] = $value;
            }
            else
            {
                $sanitized[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $sanitized;
}

/**
 * Normalize group fields.
 * @param array $field
 * @return array
 */
public static function normalize( $field )
{
    $field           = parent::normalize( $field );
    $field['fields'] = RW_Meta_Box::normalize_fields( $field['fields'] );
    return $field;
}
```

}

Comment: A 500 error is a generic "something went wrong" error that could mean one of a million other things from variables not defined to full on syntax/parsing issues. What you need to do is have a look at your web server error log which will tell you what the actual issue is instead of just guessing.

Comment: Okay can you please specify how to get that error log ?
is it through my hosting provider?

Comment: It depends on your hosting provider. Ask them and they should be able to help you.

Comment: Okay, when I mentioned that after installing the meta-box pluging I get this error doesn't that have any indications to any kind of a problem... I am now chatting with them btw

Comment: OK. StackOverflow is a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Questions should be related to specific programming problems and have a specific answer. Comments are typically reserved for requesting clarification of the question. This question appears to be pretty broad in scope (thousands of possible issues/answers) and more about wordpress/plugin support than programming which would be [outside of the scope of what SO is about](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Okay now I got an error that I can address: Fatal error: Class 'RWMB_Field' not found in /home/haddadmokhtar/public_html/wp-content/plugins/aqura-metabox-group/meta-box-group/class-rwmb-group-field.php on line 14